# How do I send actions to a UIImage Subview, delegated from a UIAlertView

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uialertview

Essentially I have a `UIAlertView` that pops up. When a user selects a button it calls itself, and based on the button index it brings up a `UIImageView` subview. My question is, because the `UIImageView` takes up a good portion of the screen it lays on top of the `UIAlertView`, so the cancel button is unseen. I was wondering if I could create actions on the UIImageView so that if it is clicked or touched up inside, the `UIAlertView`/`UIImageView` would resign and disappear?

Someone please help, I've been tooling around this for hours.

Here is the code from the button being clicked, and the button index.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex     {
// the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
if (buttonIndex == 0)
{
 //     exit(0);
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"molecule" message:molURL delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 260)];


    NSString *MyURL = molURL;

    NSString *apURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",MyURL];


    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:apURL];
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage * image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];


    //UIImage *bkgImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [imageView setImage:image1];


    [successAlert addSubview:imageView];

    [successAlert show];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyImageView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyImageView : UIImageView {



}

@end
```

MyImageView.m

```
#import "MyImageView.h"


@implementation MyImageView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        self.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

    }
    return self;
}


-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^(void) {


        self.alpha=0.0f;

        super.hidden =YES;

        UIAlertView *alert=(UIAlertView*)self.superview;


        alert.alpha=0.0f;

        [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

        //or

        //[alert removeFromSuperview];

    }];




}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

MyViewController.h

```
    @class MyImageView;
```

MyViewController.m

```
    #import "MyImageView.h"
```

then while create imageView

```
    MyImageView *specialImageView =[[MyImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 260)];
```